# Very poor speed/memory performance when using tf.data for text data

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use this code

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb

But use tf.data to handle all the text data.

I am running both over Google Colaboratory using the GPU runtime option.

Here's is the original relevant code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import collections
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from matplotlib import pylab
from six.moves import range
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

url = 'http://mattmahoney.net/dc/'

def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes):
  """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
  if not os.path.exists(filename):
    filename, _ = urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
  statinfo = os.stat(filename)
  if statinfo.st_size == expected_bytes:
    print('Found and verified %s' % filename)
  else:
    print(statinfo.st_size)
    raise Exception(
      'Failed to verify ' + filename + '. Can you get to it with a browser?')
  return filename

filename = maybe_download('text8.zip', 31344016)

def read_data(filename):
  """Extract the first file enclosed in a zip file as a list of words"""
  with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
  return data

words = read_data(filename)
print('Data size %d' % len(words))
```

Here is my best attempt to alter this to use tf.data to handle the text data.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import collections
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from matplotlib import pylab
from six.moves import range
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

url = 'http://mattmahoney.net/dc/'

def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes):
  """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
  if not os.path.exists(filename):
    filename, _ = urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
  statinfo = os.stat(filename)
  if statinfo.st_size == expected_bytes:
    print('Found and verified %s' % filename)
  else:
    print(statinfo.st_size)
    raise Exception(
      'Failed to verify ' + filename + '. Can you get to it with a browser?')
  return filename

filename = maybe_download('text8.zip', 31344016)

def read_data(filename):
  """Extract the first file enclosed in a zip file as a list of words"""
  with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( f.read(f.namelist()[0]) )
  return data

datasetTest = read_data(filename)
```

Basically I changed this line from the original

```
data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
```

to this line

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( f.read(f.namelist()[0]) )
```

The new one doesn't split the words by space like the old line,  so I had another line #datasetTest = datasetTest.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]).values) but I commented it out to try to pin point where the bottle neck is.

The old code runs within a minute or two. The new one can never finish executing. It usually runs for 30-40 minutes before colab says it has crashed and is restarting the runtime.

Comment: How are you using the dataset? Note that you can also do tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()) which will get you a Dataset but not do any processing in it (since you're reading the file from python dataset won't get you much performance anyway)

Comment: The data is a continuous sentence of words from sentences, which is used to train word2vec embeddings. I tried the line you suggested but it gives the same issue. The first time I tried it Google Colab gave me a 'runtime has died' error, second time it gave me a 'Memory usage is close to the limit' warning, but it completed it after 5 minutes. The original line only took 1 second. Could you elaborate what you mean by 'any processing in it (since you're reading the file from python dataset won't get you much performance anyway)'? I'm coming from a math background and not a CS background.

Comment: The main advantage of using tf.data is getting a speedup on your input pipeline. To get the most out of it you need to let tf do the computation instead of python. Since you're still reading and splitting from python tf.data will not get you much performance-wise, so you might as well use your original code.

Comment: Great insight, thanks! Tf.data does have an operation to split the data, but first I need to get the data into the tf.data object. I am wondering why this operation is taking so long. As far as I could find, my code is the best way to extract data from a Zip file into tf.data since tf.data doesn't do file upzip.